# Leaflet .js reference layers as variables

Tags: leaflet, layers

I am advised to reference my layers as variables rather than as functions, so I can order the layers using .bringtofront.

I have tried several combinations of var skull = L.geoJSON(fatalities)etc.)  but everything I have tried simply causes all the layers to vanish from the map.

Here's the map: https://pdxcyclesafetymap.neocities.org/

And here's the .js for one of the layers, as it works now:

```
var skull = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/blackSkull.svg',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    popupAnchor: [-10, -30],
    }); 

function fatalitiesLayer (feature, 
layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("<h1>Cyclist Fatality</h1><p> "+feature.properties.name+
    "</p>"+feature.properties.description+
    "</p>Date: "+feature.properties.date+ 
    "</p>Location: "+feature.properties.location+ 
    "</p>Cause: "+feature.properties.cause+ 
    "</p>");
    layer.setIcon(skull); 
    }


L.geoJson(fatalities,{
    onEachFeature: fatalitiesLayer
    }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Just to make things clear, do you want to achieve the ability to use featureGroup? I think this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200809/leaflet-javascript-scope-issue-within-geojson-oneachfeature-function) can be very helpful.

Comment: For point data you will probably need to use `pointToLayer`  - here's a nice example [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65964/how-can-i-change-the-style-of-marker-in-leaflet-from-geojson)

Comment: I just want to achieve the ability to order my layers -

Comment: Can you try creating an empty `L.featureGroup()` for each layer type(skulls, hazards etc) and than add the layers to each featureGroup by example:`skulls.layerAdd(layer)` in the `onEachFeature` function? By that you will create a featureGroup for each accident type (a collection of layers is [featureGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#featuregroup)

Comment: I am happy to attempt it: the hard, very hard, part, is figuring out how.

Comment: I've created a little fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/nettaB/16j3edma/7/. Please look at lines 356 (init featureGroup), 373 (add layer to group), 374 (console log the group length), 830 ( `fatalities_group.bringToFront()`). All the fatalities can be referenced by the `fatalities_group` var.